# Importing PropType value from another module results in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, es6-modules, react-proptypes

Disclaimer: I am new to React and ES6, so please be patient!

In FacetGroup*s*.js, I define some patterns to be used to compare using PropTypes that are used across the app in various modules.  It works just fine within this file

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import FacetGroup from './FacetGroup';

/* ... */
const FacetGroups = ({ facets }) => (
    <div>
        {Object.keys(facets).map( facetName => {
            const facet = facets[facetName];

            return (
                <section key={facetName}>
                    <header>{facet.displayName}</header>
                    <FacetGroup group={facet} groupName={facetName} />
                </section>
            );
        })}
    </div>
);

const GROUP_PROP_TYPE = PropTypes.shape({
  displayName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  /* ... */
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  isShowingAll: PropTypes.bool
});

FacetGroups.propTypes = {
    facets: PropTypes.objectOf( GROUP_PROP_TYPE ).isRequired /* This works fine */
}

/* ... */

export { GROUP_PROP_TYPE, /* ... */ };
```

Then, in FacetGroup.js (sibling file), I import the variable, and use it in a FacetGroup proptype definition:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { GROUP_PROP_TYPE, /* ... */ } from './FacetGroups';

const FacetGroup = ({ group, groupName }) => (
    <span>I am a Facet Group</span>
);

FacetGroup.propTypes = {
    group: GROUP_PROP_TYPE.isRequired,
    groupName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

This gives me a runtime error in the browser console, where `GROUP_PROP_TYPE` is not defined (and therefore `isRequired` is failing.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRequired' of undefined

I'm running this JS file through gulp using webpackStream and webpack - this is my config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { 
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

Could someone help me understand why this is failing? Is it something to do with the order of evaluation?  I am having trouble debugging effectively in the browser the way I would in normal JS since it's all compiled through webpack and babel...

Comment: Maybe the root cause of your problem is the circular dependancies this seems to setup. You should try to define `GROUP_PROP_TYPE` elsewhere

Comment: @Apolo - you're completely right (deleted my previous comment, I was exporting things incorrectly) - it was the circular dependencies.  Please write this up as an answer, and I will mark it as the accepted one :)

Comment: done :) Glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid circular dependancies.
Try to define `GROUP_PROP_TYPE` in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

in in FacetGroup.js define FacetGroup correctly

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { GROUP_PROP_TYPE, /* ... */ } from './FacetGroups';

/* ... */

const FacetGroups = {
  facets: PropTypes.objectOf(GROUP_PROP_TYPE).isRequired /* This works fine */
}
```

Comment: In FacetGroups.js, FacetGroups is a React Component with the facets: `propTypes.objectOf(GROUP_PROP_TYPE)` structure. In FacetGroup.js, FacetGroup (singular) is a React Component with the `group: GROUP_PROP_TYPE.isRequired, groupName: PropTypes.string.isRequired` structure. I'm not sure what you're "correcting"...  I've updated my answer to have a little more context

Comment: i am "correcting" when i define FacetGroups so when you import it will be defined and obviously avoid the error  which is the main problem in your question

Comment: I am not importing (nor do I want to) a variable `FacetGroups` into FacetGroup. I want `GROUP_PROP_TYPE` (currently it is undefined) from the file FacetGroups.js so that I may use it when I'm declaring the prop types for a locally-defined `FacetGroup` React Component.  @Apolo 's answer was correct - the circular dependencies were what was causing the issue.